# Selection textrange IE, startposition is changed

Tags: internet-explorer, contenteditable, textselection

My startposition gets changed when I select some text with "shift + arrow_left" let me explain in example:

**Example:**
- contenteditable div
- inserted charcode 0182 (¶) by myself = the variable: hardReturn

**text in div:**
test¶
abc

**code on key up + arrow_left:**

```
    var myRange = document.selection.createRange(); 
myRange.moveStart('character', -1); 
var charVoor = myRange.text.substring(0, 1);

if(charVoor == hardReturn){
    myRange.moveEnd('character', -1);
    myRange.select();   
}else{
}
```

**So my problem:**
my cursor is between "b" and "c", i start selecting... I got "ab" under selection, then I do another selection to the left, my selection will jump automaticly before the "¶", but after that my startposition of my selection is before "¶" and not between "b" & "c" where I started.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a clone of the `TextRange` object to check `hardReturn`:

```
var myRange = document.selection.createRange();
var chkRange = myRange.duplicate();
chkRange.moveStart('character', -1); 
var charVoor = chkRange.text.substring(0, 1);

if(charVoor == hardReturn){
    chkRange.moveEnd('character', -1);
    ....  
}
```

I'm not sure what is the final text you want in the selection. If needed, you can move the original `myRange` in relation to `chkRange` with `setEndPoint()` method, or use `collapse()` to collapse the range between `a` and `b`.

You can find `setEndPoint()` and other methods and properties in `TextRange` from [MSDN: Traversal and Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)